# T-SQL compilation issue for simple query involving DMV

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

For some reason, the following query which uses the `sys.dm_exec_requests` DMV and the `sys.dm_exec_sql_text` DMV fails to compile:

```
SELECT er.session_id, es.[text]
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests AS er 
  CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(er.[sql_handle]) AS es
```

The query excerpt above is part of a much larger (and more complex) query which fails, because this smaller query will not execute, giving me the syntax error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3 Incorrect syntax near '.'.

The query seems simple enough, yet it looks like the T-SQL parser is balking at the `er.sql_handle`. I thought this might be an escaping issue and tried `er.[sql_handle]`, but sadly got the same error.

Comment: No syntax error here, running your exact query as given against a 2008 server/database.

Comment: I wonder if this is an issues with SQL Server 2008 R2. I am using: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1797.0 (X64)   Jun  1 2011 15:43:18   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get this error when running it in the context of a DB in SQL Server 2000 compatibility mode. Try running it under the context of one of the system databases instead.

Comment: Was just trying to post essentially the same answer as this.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head! My DB was set to SQL Server 2000 compatibility mode. I changed it to SQL Server 2008 and the query executes just fine. Thank you!

Comment: By the way, how do you set the default compatibility mode to something reasonable (e.g., SQL Server 2008 R2) for newly created databases at an instance level?

Comment: @Michael - I assume they take it off `model`?

Comment: @Martin, well done! The model DB is where defaults for new databases are taken from. I changed my model DB to use SQL Server 2008 compatibility and then created a new DB. Sure enough, the correct compatibility level was selected. Thanks for all your help, I was really stomped with this one...

Comment: No problem. Always a bit of a head scratcher!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using 2008 or 2008 R2 and `EXEC sp_dbcmptlevel 'databasename'` give below 90 then use the script below:

```
ALTER DATABASE databasename SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 100
```